# How to set up airport express to be dns server for my home network?

Tags: network, airport

I currently have an airport express as my router.  I've configured it to look to an external dns server.  on the inside of my network my machines are told to look to the airport express for dns.

This seems to work.  Now:

I have ipfw set up on my macbook.  It seems to me that Bonjour should be the protocol inside the network.  I certainly can't turn off Bonjour, address resolution fails then.

What I think is happening is DNS goes to router, then mDNSResponder handles from there.  Is this acutally the case?

I'm asking this because I keep on having the Airport Express try to connect to port 53 with dns packets.  This is confusing me.  Is this the right way to set it up?

Comment: Do you mean the airport express is trying to send DNS packets to your macbook and you don't think it should?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly it.